# Browserify requiring variable is undefined

Tags: typescript, webpack, module, browserify

I recently upgraded a whole frontend TypeScript project to use modules (import/export). I'm using browserify with tsify to compile it. However, the outputted bundle.js file is unable to run, giving me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myvariable ' of undefined
```

`myvariable` is loaded through:

```
import { myvariable } from './globalvars';
```

And in globalvars it's defined as:

```
export let myvariable = 'hello world!';
```

Logging out myvariable is gived undefined, and logging out just the require statement just logs

```
{__esmodule: true }
```

I tried switching the whole project to CommonJS, so using require() and module.exports(), but I get the exact same issue.

THEN I tried using Webpack, used a typescript config and that is also unrunnable.

I also tried piping the sources through babel before bundling, same issue.

Here is the gulp task I wrote for compiling:

```
gulp.task('compile-scripts', function (finished) {
    console.log('Compiling scripts.');
    browserify({
            standalone: 'main'
        })
        .add('src/scripts/scriptloader.ts')
        .plugin("tsify", {
            noImplicitAny: false,
            module: 'CommonJS'
        })
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('debug/js')).on('end', function () {
            finished();
        });
});
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I've spent two days on this and am quite frustrated. Thanks!

Comment: I put together a test of this and was able to get it working so I suspect it will be a problem in your build pipeline. I'm currently struggling with gulp, browserify & tsify myself, but my build worked for this. Can you share your build config?

Comment: @Geoff I just added the gulp task to the question

Comment: I put together a test using your gulpfile and apart from having to put quotes around babelify in the transform it worked. I guess I needed the quotes because I'm not explicitly importing babelify in the gulpfile, so I must be picking it up from within browserify. I put together a gist so you can compare notes: https://gist.github.com/GeoffCapper/9be1acf4c37f256584e1087f1e634ac3

Comment: Hmm, I've been doing more thorough investigating thanks to your example. Having webpack analyze the project says there are circular dependencies as a warning, are circular dependencies not allowed for bundling? It's a large enough project where removing the circular dependencies would be an undertaking in its own roght

Comment: That could certainly be causing you problems. There are a lot of questions on here about resolving circular dependencies, and it looks like a lot of people get tripped up by the fact it will compile but not run.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm out of options then, as fixing the circular dependencies would require essentially a rewrite of a large portion/redesign of the architecture. Thank you for all your help!